# Dota 2 config file in steam gets reset all the time!

Tags: steam, dota-2

I've just started playing dota 2 for a week now and have played LoL for a year. I've researched some stuff about binding and editing the config file. I've found what I wanted to do, however, every time I exit dota 2, the config file gets reset, and the things I've added won't work after reopening dota2.

I really don't want to type approx 10 lines of code in the console everytime I've to restart dota 2.

The core problem is that some things in the config file gets removed, some gets readjusted to the original and some do not work even if they stay there.

Config file path:
E:*MyFolder*\Steam\SteamApps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\cfg

Here are some example:

These codes get removed every time:

> alias "leftclick" "+sixense_left_click; -sixense_left_click"
>
> alias "atkGround" "mc_attack; leftclick"

These codes are there, but never work. Worked only the first time:

> bind "MOUSE4" "atkGround"
>
> bind "F1" "dota_camera_setpos -2273.898682 1232.745483 982.072876"
>
> bind "F2" "dota_camera_setpos 3035.773438 -2972.680176 966.072937"

This one gets readjusted to 600 every time!

> dota_minimap_hero_size 900

Is there a way to make these permanent?!

Thanks in advance!

-Iraqi_Warrior

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer on reddit. 
[Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/learndota2/comments/28qsqy/problem_with_dota_2_config_file_need_help/)

I basically have to create an autoexec.cfg file in the same folder and paste my code there instead.

Comment: You may want to mark your answer as the correct one to close the question!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Don't use autoexe to put bindings, autoexe has default values, instead make a new cfg file in the same folder as the config and name it bindings, then right at the top put sometheing like //These are my bindings 
and then after that line put exec bindings.cfg
that will call your bindings everytime the game starts and if you ever want to change or update your bindings you won't danger the default settings or break anything.

Comment: @Jonathan What? autoexec.cfg is the proper location for custom configuration settings. config.cfg is where default values are stored and modified.

Answer (score 0):

One way of quickly fixing this is to bind it to a key. Bindings will be saved when you exit the game. 
For a similar config I have bound l.

Command example: bind "l" "dota_minimap_hero_size 900"

Although the hero size is not permanent it can be switched on with a simple press of the l button while in game.